# Intuit Anywhere - Invalid Token Exception

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to pass requirement AppCenter WF 1.0. My log is here:

http://pastebin.com/jqqLWury

I notice that my OauthResponse page is visited twice:

CCC : Info 4/8/2013 2:40:22 PM OauthResponse has been visited on 4/8/2013 2:40:22 PM
CCC : Info 4/8/2013 2:40:26 PM OauthResponse has been visited on 4/8/2013 2:40:26 PM

The log I posted above also seems to hit my page twice.

I try and login at https://appcenter.intuit.com/TryBuy/IA/MYID. I receive a page asking to connect to my app. When I connect and click authorize, I am sent to myapp.com/openid and redirected to myapp.com/home/index. I receive an access token, an access token secret, and a realm. When I try to authenticate with these credentials, it fails.

*I notice that the app is never added to my company list of apps.*

I am using the Intuit Azure SDK. In my development area, are these settings correct?

**App URL: myapp.com/openid**

**Disconnect Landing url: myapp.com/disconnect**

**Manage Users Url: myapp.com/OauthResponse**

**OpenId URL: https://www.myapp.com/openid**

**Host Name Domain: myapp.com**

I am using my development consumer key and my development consumer key secret. How come I am getting bad credentials?

Here is my error:

Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized
   at Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsExceptionManager.HandleException(IdsException idsException)
   at Intuit.Ipp.Core.ServiceContext.GetQBOPartitionedURL(String qboServiceEndpoint)
   at Intuit.Ipp.Core.ServiceContext.GetBaseURL()
   at Intuit.Ipp.Core.ServiceContext..ctor(IRequestValidator requestValidator, String

Here is my code:

```
string Authenticate()
    {
        string accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"].ToString();
        string accessTokenSecret = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString();
        string companyID = HttpContext.Current.Session["realm"].ToString();
        // now auth to IA
        OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString());
        ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, accessToken, companyID, IntuitServicesType.QBO);
        dataServices = new DataServices(context);
        return "OK";
    }
```

If I log in through my website without using that URL, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you turn on logging and get the request and response that is getting the error

Comment: OK, I added the log: http://pastebin.com/jqqLWury

Comment: I dont see the request or response there. Its the XML request that you are sending, including the headers that I need to see.

Comment: My site is on production (cloudcartconnector.com.) How do I get the XML for the request and the response that you are seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my app URL was incorrect in the app center.

In my case, the app URL should be http://www.cloudcartconnector.com/OpenId and my OpenIdUrl should be https://www.cloudcartconnector.com/DirectConnectToIntuit